# How to get Primary Key Value if not Present in Foreign Key via Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've following query which display the result as required, but I need to get the missing Primary Key Values missing in the result:

```
SELECT  
   tbl1.SignedByUserID, tbl2.FullName, 
   COUNT(tbl1.OutletID) AS TotalSignups, 
   DATENAME(Month, tbl1.SignupDate) AS Month
FROM    
   dbo.tblMer_Outlet AS tbl1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   dbo.tblGen_Users AS tbl2 ON tbl1.SignedByUserID = tbl2.UserID
WHERE   
   (tbl1.SignupDate >= '2014-04-01 00:00:00' 
    AND tbl1.SignupDate <= '2014-04-30 23:59:59')
GROUP BY 
   tbl1.SignedByUserID, tbl2.FullName, DATENAME(Month, tbl1.SignupDate)
ORDER BY 
   tbl2.FullName
```

This query returns the following result:

```
SignedByUserID     FullName       TotalSignups     Month
--------------------------------------------------------
9                  Babu Raj       16               April
11                 Faheem         19               April
39                 Fasil Abbas    16               April
29                 Hafiz Suleman  10               April
12                 Hussain Abbas  16               April
15                 Khawaja Aashan 33               April
33                 M. Danyal      16               April
41                 M. Qasim       01               April
32                 M. Yousuf      16               April
37                 Noman Yousaf   14               April
40                 Sajid Saleem   16               April
5                  Sales          10               April
20                 Tauseef Anees  23               April
35                 Umar Akbar     11               April
22                 Willie         09               April
```

but my User table contains 1 more value:

```
38                 Bilal Mateen
```

which does not have a signup for the month of April, but I need it to be available for this or any upcoming month.

Not specific to the user. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mysql or sql-server ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it fixed...

```
SELECT A.UserID, A.FullName, ISNULL(B.TotalSignups,0) AS TotalSignups, B.Month FROM
(
SELECT UserID, FullName
FROM tblGen_Users
WHERE GroupID = 4
) AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT SignedByUserID, COUNT(1) AS TotalSignups, DATENAME(Month, SignupDate) AS Month
FROM tblMer_Outlet
WHERE SignupDate BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-05-01'
GROUP BY SignedByUserID, DATENAME(Month, SignupDate)
) AS B ON A.UserID = B.SignedByUserID
ORDER BY A.FullName
```

If needs some improvement, please suggest.